# Redirect custom recurring payment method to payment gateway after order is placed in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, redirect, payment-gateway, recurring

I am trying to implement a custom recurring payment module for Magento 1.9.

I follow a tutorial from [ModulesGarden Blog](https://www.blog.modulesgarden.com/recurring-payments-in-magento?fbclid=IwAR3gut5vfrtHtjSE1W3SdDbOmb4V4_jvaqUuPNMTsbHrxdPRNyUTP4CQsfw) combined with Paypal Express.

I was able to create a new payment method that is showing in checkout only for recurring products. If I create only a fake request for testing like in the tutorial, everything it is working well, the orders are created, the profile it is created, I can cancel or suspend the profile from My Account.

The problem is that I don't know how to redirect on the gateway page after order is placed. Until now I tried to add in my payment model the method `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` which is called in `saveOrder()` method, but this doesn't work because the method looks like this:

```
public function saveOrder()
{
    $this->validate();
    $isNewCustomer = false;
    switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
        case self::METHOD_GUEST:
            $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
            break;
        case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
            $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
            $isNewCustomer = true;
            break;
        default:
            $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
            break;
    }

    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());
    $service->submitAll();

    if ($isNewCustomer) {
        try {
            $this->_involveNewCustomer();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    $this->_checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId())
        ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId())
        ->clearHelperData();

    $order = $service->getOrder();
    if ($order) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
            array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$this->getQuote()));

        /**
         * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
         * eg: paypal standard ipn
         */
        $redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
        /**
         * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
         */
        if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
            try {
                $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }

        // add order information to the session
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
            ->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl)
            ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());

        // as well a billing agreement can be created
        $agreement = $order->getPayment()->getBillingAgreement();
        if ($agreement) {
            $this->_checkoutSession->setLastBillingAgreementId($agreement->getId());
        }
    }

    // add recurring profiles information to the session
    $profiles = $service->getRecurringPaymentProfiles();
    if ($profiles) {
        $ids = array();
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $ids[] = $profile->getId();
        }
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastRecurringProfileIds($ids);
        // TODO: send recurring profile emails
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'checkout_submit_all_after',
        array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote(), 'recurring_profiles' => $profiles)
    );

    return $this;
}
```

The method is called only if there is an order, but there it isn't because when we use recurring profiles the order is created later, so only the code inside the `if ($profiles) {}` runs and there is no `redirectUrl`.

Then I tried to use the method `getCheckoutRedirectUrl()` like it's used in PayPal Express. Now I am redirected to payment gateway but the problem is that this method is called in `savePaymentAction()` and that means that I am redirected before the order review step.

Is there a possible to redirect to payment gateway only after the order is placed, somewhere in `submitRecurringProfile()` method? I don't want to remove the review order step because the customers need to accept the terms and conditions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after days of research and debugging I just found out a simple solution.

First, because we cannot change core files, I just copy the `Onepage.php` from core:

> app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

to:

> app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php

and I made some changes in `saveOrder()` method. Now this method looks like this:

```
public function saveOrder()
{
    $this->validate();
    $isNewCustomer = false;
    switch ($this->getCheckoutMethod()) {
        case self::METHOD_GUEST:
            $this->_prepareGuestQuote();
            break;
        case self::METHOD_REGISTER:
            $this->_prepareNewCustomerQuote();
            $isNewCustomer = true;
            break;
        default:
            $this->_prepareCustomerQuote();
            break;
    }

    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $this->getQuote());
    $service->submitAll();

    if ($isNewCustomer) {
        try {
            $this->_involveNewCustomer();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    $this->_checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId())
        ->setLastSuccessQuoteId($this->getQuote()->getId())
        ->clearHelperData();

    $order = $service->getOrder();
    /**
     * a flag to set that there will be redirect to third party after confirmation
     * eg: paypal standard ipn
     */
    $redirectUrl = $this->getQuote()->getPayment()->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();

    if ($order) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after',
            array('order'=>$order, 'quote'=>$this->getQuote()));

        /**
         * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
         */
        if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
            try {
                $order->queueNewOrderEmail();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }

        // add order information to the session
        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId())
            ->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl)
            ->setLastRealOrderId($order->getIncrementId());

        // as well a billing agreement can be created
        $agreement = $order->getPayment()->getBillingAgreement();
        if ($agreement) {
            $this->_checkoutSession->setLastBillingAgreementId($agreement->getId());
        }
    }

    // add recurring profiles information to the session
    $profiles = $service->getRecurringPaymentProfiles();
    if ($profiles) {
        $this->_checkoutSession->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            $ids[] = $profile->getId();
        }

        $this->_checkoutSession->setLastRecurringProfileIds($ids);
        // TODO: send recurring profile emails
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'checkout_submit_all_after',
        array('order' => $order, 'quote' => $this->getQuote(), 'recurring_profiles' => $profiles)
    );

    return $this;
}
```

The differences are that I defined `$redirectUrl` even if there is no order and I set it to the `$checkoutSession` in both cases if exists order or recurring profile. You can compare the `saveOrder()` methods from my question and my answer to see de differences.

After that you have to create the `getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl()` method in your payment model and everything should work perfect.

Hope this helps other devs!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same issue and I approached it in a different manner.

I created an observer for the *checkout_submit_all_after* event and inside the the observer I check if any **recurring profiles** have been added to the event data. If so, then I force a redirect to my action.

Here is the observer method code

```
public function checkoutSubmitAllFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
Mage::log(__FUNCTION__, Zend_Log::DEBUG, $this->logFileName);

if(0 < sizeof($observer->getEvent()->getData()['recurring_profiles'])){
  $recurringProfileId = $observer->getEvent()->getData()['recurring_profiles'][0]['profile_id'];

  if($recurringProfileId){
    /* Construct the redirect URL. */
    $redirectUrl = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', ['_query' => ['profileId' => $recurringProfileId]]);
    /* Set the redirect URL. */
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setRedirectUrl($redirectUrl);
  }
}
return $this;
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: yes, this sound like a good approach too, maybe this will help someone because I already made like I write in the answer..